# How to avoid oscillation by async event based systems?

Tags: algorithms, concurrency

Imagine a system where there are data sources which need to be kept in sync. A simple example is model - view data binding by MVC. Now I intend to describe these kind of systems with data sources and hubs. Data sources are publishing and subscribing for events and hubs are relaying events to data sources. By handling an event a data source will change it state described in the event. By publishing an event the data source puts its current state to the event, so other data sources can use that information to change their state accordingly.

The only problem with this system, that events can be reflected from the hub or from the other data sources, and that can put the system into an infinite oscillation (by async or infinite loop by sync). For example

```
A -- data source
B -- data source
H -- hub

A -> H -> A -- reflection from the hub
A -> H -> B -> H -> A -- reflection from another data source
```

By sync it is relatively easy to solve this issue. You can compare the current state with the event, and if they are equal, you don't change the state and raise the same event again.

By async I could not find a solution yet. The state comparison does not work by async event handling because there is eventual consistency, and new events can be published in an inconsistent state causing the same oscillation. For example:

```
A(*->x) -> H -> B(y->x)
    -- can go parallel with
B(*->y) -> H -> A(x->y)
    -- so first A changes to x state while B changes to y state
    -- then B changes to x state while A changes to y state
    -- and so on for eternity...
```

What do you think is there an algorithm to solve this problem? If there is a solution, is it possible to extend it to prevent oscillation caused by multiple hubs, multiple different events, etc... ?

**update:**

I don't think I can make this work without a lot of effort. I think this problem is just the same as we have by syncing multiple databases in a distributed system. So I think what I really need is constraints if I want to prevent this problem in an automatic way. What constraints do you suggest?

Comment: You cannot always describe your model with DAG. For example by an MVC system you can have a model bound to views with input fields. You cannot say the user to write into the memory in order to change the model, so you can send events to change the content of the input fields ...

Comment: Can you add a link about the presentation you mentioned?

Comment: Searching for "rick hickey immutability presentation", it is the third result...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have designed your system such that a data source changes state (and fires an event) for *every* event that it receives, then you have an inherently instable (oscillating) system if that data source is involved in a loop of events.

The only ways to avoid oscillations in such a system are:

1. Somehow ensure that the events received by such a data source don't originate from itself (directly or indirectly through other events). This is harder than it seems and the trouble is that you generally don't see an error until the oscillations actually happen.
2. Ensure that each data source has some combinations of states and events where it either ignores the event or at least doesn't fire a new event.
   So, in the case of the simple reflection of event E, data source A should ignore event E if it is received in state x.
   In general, in every event-driven system there will be a number of events that don't make sense when received in certain states. It is those events that should dampen out any oscillations that occur.

The main source for oscillations that remains would be two (external) events that occur at the same time and try to put the system into different states. These kinds of oscillations are inherent to the system and will have to be addressed on a case by case basis. Generally, that would involve preferring one state over the other and ignoring the events that would trigger the oscillations when received in the preferred state.

Comment: Just this week I cut out instances of your #1 happening in my remote control app, and I solved it just like you describe.

The "trick" I used was to have internal maintenance signals for local state maintenance and external for control inputs. Keeping this arms-length gap stops the feedback loops from forming.

Comment: I think in my case the hubs should ignore events related to the same state they already delivered once. I think adding an externalEvent (or state or context or transaction) property to every event and check that would do the trick.

Comment: Another huge problem can be event order, for example some parts of the system can end up in [x,y,z] state while other parts in [x,z,y] state. Simply ignoring the y transition if it comes after z does not necessarily solve the problem always. Sometimes it is necessary to defer the z state transition until the y transition comes in. I think the first step to solve these kind of problems is having a local event storage which contains all the external events, which led to the current state.